# Using setters in Javascript to "override" properties

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, setter, super

The [MDN page about `set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Description) seems to state that an

> [ECMAScript 2015] setter must not appear in an object literal ... with a
>   data entry for the same property.

However when using the super keyword this no longer seems to apply.

```
class Foo {
    constructor(bar){
        this.bar = bar
    }

    set bar(newBar){
        if (!newBar.match(/\w+/))
            throw Error("Invalid bar value")
        // I can use super despite not being a derived class.
        return super.bar = newBar
    }
}
const baz = new Foo("Baz")
baz.bar = "new value" // No recursion
```

This seems like a useful feature as the property doesn't have to be "hidden" by prefixing it with an underscore. Plus I don't have to mess with the property enumerability to avoid the "hidden" version from showing in a loop or serialization.

But the `set` syntax is a bit of a black-box and I can't tell what it's actually doing.

Am I breaking something here or is it okay to use?

Also what is `super` referencing here?

Comment: That's not an object literal, it's a class... so what's your question? Also, `super` in this case references `Object` (all JS objects inherit from Object unless you specifically tell them not to, e.g. `Object.create(null)`).

Comment: `super` there is actually `Object.prototype`, will be `Object` on static methods though. Also, since ES7, `Object.prototype` is immutable so on ES7 environments this is a noop.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @MinusFour interesting, I don't know much of ES7. But the assignment is still on the actual object: `baz.hasOwnProperty('bar') == true` no the prototype so why would it be a  'noop'?

Comment: "*It must not appear in an object literal with another set or with a data entry for the same property.*" has nothing to do with what you are experiencing here. You always can shadow or overwrite a setter property with a data property, you just are not allowed to specify both at once in the same object literal. Similar to how duplicate property names in the same literal are (were) forbidden.

Comment: Whats forbidden is `{bar:'a', set bar(v){ this.bar = v }}`, however the `super` refers to the `Object` (as by default classes extend `Object`) and their setter and getter 'methods'. So it will assign to your current object, yes, not the super, but it will use the set/get method from `Object`, not your `class`.

Answer (score 3):

> This seems like a useful feature as the property doesn't have to be "hidden" by prefixing it with an underscore or something. Plus I don't have to mess with the property enumerability to avoid the "hidden" version from showing in a loop or serialization.

No, it's not useful. It's a hack at best, and doesn't do what you expect.

There is nothing hidden here at all. You are creating a new property with the name `bar` on the instance itself, shadowing any getters/setters you had defined on the prototype. The second assignment does not get your setter caller. Also the instance property is a normal enumerable property, so it will show up in `for in` loops and serialisation.

> Also what is "super" referencing here?

The `super` keyword refers to the prototype of the object that the method (or setter) is defined on, i.e. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype)`. This is the `Object.prototype` in your case, since your `class Foo` doesn't `extend` anything.

The `.foo` access will be looked up on that prototype, and would normally find a method that you inherited from your parent class or something. When using that, the property reference `super.foo` will however make the receiver of the operation (i.e. what would the `this` keyword in a method invocation) be the current `this` instance, not the prototype.

In your case, it's not a method call but an assignment. This could run a setter inherited from the parent class, but in your case there is no `Object.prototype.foo` property so it will fall back to standard assignment on the target - and that target is the `baz` instance itself, where a new own property will be created.

So no, it is not okay to use.